How do I read global configuration file and use these in a vue3 app
What I've tried sofar:
in main.js
//Configuration
import * as config from '/config/settings.js'
app.config.globalProperties.apiUrl = config.apiUrl
app.config.globalProperties.imageBaseUrl = config.imageBaseUrl

in public/config/serttings.js
const apiUrl = 'https://example.com/'
const imageBaseUrl ='https://example.com/assets/images/equipment/'


export { apiUrl, imageBaseUrl }

Access the global settings with:

const url = this.apiUrl + 'Reservation';

This seems to work but if I do a npm run dev there is an error and suggestion to change settings.js to
import * as config from '/config/settings.js?url'

But in production this does not work.
I get

src/main.js (30:44): "apiUrl" is not exported by
"../../../../../config/settings.js?url", imported by "src/main.js".
src/main.js (31:50): "imageBaseUrl" is not exported by
"../../../../../config/settings.js?url", imported by "src/main.js".

The docs do talk about app.config but are not very conclusive how to use configs from a file.
What would be the proper way to import settings from a file in a Vue3 app.
